# Async callback on mocked object not awaiting

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, async-await, moq

I am attempting to mock a complicated situation for unit testing:

```
_mockController = new Mock<IController>();
_mockController.Setup(tc => tc.Interrupt(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()))
    .Callback<Func<Task>>(async f => await f.Invoke());
```

Where `IController` has a void method `Interrupt(Func<Task>> f)`, which queues some work to be done.

My objects under test do call `Interrupt()`, and I can verify the call like so:

```
_mockController.Verify(tc => tc.Interrupt(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()), Times.Once);
```

...but when the argument `Func<Task>` is invoked in the callback, the `await` keyword is not respected in the `Task`: the execution of the test continues before the `Task` finishes (despite the `await` in the callback).  One symptom of this is that adding an `await Task.Delay(1000)` in the `Interrupt()` `Task` argument turns a passing test into a failing test.

Is this behavior due to a nuance of how threads or `Task`s are handled during test?  Or a limitation of Moq?  My test methods have this signature:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test_Name()
{
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's a limitation of Moq, but you'll have to raise an issue with them to make sure.

Comment: I opened [this issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/256) with Moq.  I will update with their response.

Comment: My solution is to write a stubbed implementation of IController that basically is a custom Mock: it keeps track of invocations and runs these interrupts asynchronously in a method returning `Task`, which is key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Callback` can't return a value, and thus shouldn't be used to execute asynchronous code (or synchronous code that needs to return a value). `Callback` is a kind of "injection point" that you can hook into to examine the parameters passed *to* the method, but not modify what it returns.

If you want a lambda mock, you can just use `Returns`:

```
_mockController.Setup(tc => tc.Interrupt(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()))
    .Returns(async f => await f());
```

(I'm assuming `Interrupt` returns `Task`).

> the execution of the test continues before the Task finishes (despite the await in the callback).

Yes, since `Callback` can't return a value, it's always typed as `Action`/`Action<...>`, so your `async` lambda ends up being an `async void` method, with [all the problems that brings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (as described in my MSDN article).

**Update:**

> Interrupt() is actually a void method: what it does is queue the function (the argument) until the IController can be bothered to stop what it is doing. Then it invokes the function--which returns a Task--and awaits that Task

You can mock that behavior then, if this would work:

```
List<Func<Task>> queue = new List<Func<Task>>();
_mockController.Setup(tc => tc.Interrupt(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()))
    .Callback<Func<Task>>(f => queue.Add(f));

... // Code that calls Interrupt

// Start all queued tasks and wait for them to complete.
await Task.WhenAll(queue.Select(f => f()));

... // Assert / Verify
```

Comment: `Interrupt()` is actually a void method: what it does is queue the function (the argument) until the `IController` can be bothered to stop what it is doing.  Then it invokes the function--which returns a `Task`--and `await`s that `Task`.  I see what you mean about it becoming `async void` behind the scenes, and  will look into that more.

Comment: @jdslepp: Updated my answer with mock code that more closely aligns with those semantics.