# Polly verify how many times httpclient timed out/retried in a Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, polly

This is not a fully working solution, just parts of the code to make the question cleaner and more readable.

I have read the Polly's documentation [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Unit-testing-with-Polly#2-i-want-to-unit-test-that-the-polly-policies-i-apply-actually-do-what-they-say-on-the-tin), however I really need to test whether the following TimeoutPolicy's `onTimeoutAsync` delegate is being hit (also, in case of wrapping TimeoutPolicy along with RetryPolicy - how many **TIMES** it has been hit) after the httpClient times out:

```
public static TimeoutPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> TimeoutPolicy
{
    get
    {
        return Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(1, onTimeoutAsync: (context, timeSpan, task) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout delegate fired after " + timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
}
```

TimeoutPolicy is set to timeout after 1 second of not receiving anything from HTTP client (HttpClient's mock is delayed for 4 seconds as shown below)

```
var httpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

httpMessageHandler.Protected()
.Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
.Callback(() => Thread.Sleep(4000))//Delayed here
.Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
    Content = new StringContent("Some response body", Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
}));

var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler.Object);
```

Policies are mocked to be able to call .Verify() on it for Assertion:

```
var mockedPolicies = new Mock<Policies>();
```

I execute the call with a mocked HTTP Client and a mocked Timeout policy:

```
await mockedPolicies.Object.TimeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync(ct => _httpClient.PostAsync("", new StringContent("Some request body"), ct), CancellationToken.None);
```

Assertion:

```
mockedPolicies.Verify(p => p.TimeoutDelegate(It.IsAny<Context>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan>(), It.IsAny<Task>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

However, test outcome says it has been called 0 times instead of 1.
Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the test code posted does not return a cancellable Task, at the value mocked for `SendAsync` to return. In that aspect it is not mirroring the way `HttpClient.SendAsync(...)` behaves.

And Polly Timeout policy with the default `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` [operates by timing-out `CancellationToken`, so the delegates you execute must respond to co-operative cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415086/).

---

**Detail:**

All `async` calls run synchronously until the first `await` statement.  In the posted test code, both:

```
// [1]
.Callback(() => Thread.Sleep(4000))//Delayed here
```

and:

```
// [2]
.Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
    Content = new StringContent("Some response body", Encoding.UTF8, " text/xml")
})
```

contain no `await` statement. So [1] and [2] will run *fully synchronously on the calling thread* (for the full four seconds), until they return the completed `Task` returned by `Task.FromResult`.  At no point do they return a 'hot' (running) `Task` which TimeoutPolicy can govern - the calling policy doesn't regain control until the synchronous four-second execution has completed. And [1] and [2] don't respond to any `CancellationToken`. So the calling timeout policy can never time it out.

Afaik [there is no CallbackAsync(...) in Moq at this time](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/256#issuecomment-215121544), so you need to move the `Thread.Sleep` into the `Returns(() => )` lambda expression, as a cancellable `await Task.Delay(...)`, to simulate the way `HttpClient.SendAsync(...)` behaves.  Something like this:

```
httpMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", 
        ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .Returns<object, CancellationToken>(async (request, cancellationToken) => {
        await Task.Delay(4000, cancellationToken); // [3]
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            Content = new StringContent("Some response body", Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
        };
    });
```

In this code, TimeoutPolicy regains control at the `await` at [3], and the `cancellationToken` has control to cancel the running `Task`.

Comment: See also these past Polly issues for longer explanation of the same point, if useful: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/318 ; https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/340 . This SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583780/ relates to Moq not offering a `CallbackAsync(...)`, as does this on Moq Github: https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/256

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Great content from you as always!
I had to use a generic .Returns<object, CancellationToken>, but apart from that the HttpClient mock works perfectly and times out the policy.

Comment: Thanks @Kalnius . Updated the answer to add the generic type parameters.